# AxaptaUserManger not initialized

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

We recently have an issue when importing users through the user import wizard.
As soon as we active the tab where you can specifiy the domain, we receive an error stating that the axaptaUserManager object is null.

On the form, this is the line where the userManager is instantiated but the result is null.

mgr = new AxaptaUserManager();

I could already point out that it is probably something with the machine itself, because it only happens on the sharepoint machine where the portal should be installed. Also the portal installer log shows the same error.

Anyone who has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this with a user with administrative rights in the Active Directory Domain you work in.

I have usually got problems with user creation (specifically, activating them) when I try to do so with a user with no administrative rights in Domain.